# How can I hide last custom div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `Div` like this and i want set attribute to last my custom div `(HRDIV)` after that i need to set hide to hidden last `hrdiv`

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="cols">
      <p>Content number 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hrdiv">

      <div class="cols">
        <p>Content number 2</p>
      </div>

      <div class="hrdiv">

        <div class="cols">
          <p>Content number 3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="hrdiv">

        </div>

      </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dxqco8t0/

many thanks to your help my friends ...

Comment: `document.querySelector(".hrdiv:last")`

Comment: @MJNBelief How does this snippet help to understand the problem/question? O.o

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @Andreas, what does MIJNBelief have to do with it?

Comment: @Barmar: Have they added a `:last` pseudo-class and I haven't heard of it? I [don't see it listed](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/). (jQuery's is an addition.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder lol, I just assumed they were adopting everything from jQuery....

Comment: @trincot He converted the code into a snippet which, imho, is useless in this case, hence my question

Comment: @Barmar: :-) No, some of jQuery's additions are pretty at odds with CSS's philosophy, I suspect `:last` would be a hard sell.

Comment: @Andreas Maybe any one help you with Snippte, So they can use **Copy snippte to answer** bottun :)

Comment: You can not use css ? With css selectors is possible . just select with div:last-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var allHrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#content .hrdiv');
allHrDivs[allHrDivs.length -1].classList.add('xxx');
```

```css
#content .xxx {
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="cols">
      <p>Content number 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hrdiv">

      <div class="cols">
        <p>Content number 2</p>
      </div>

      <div class="hrdiv">

        <div class="cols">
          <p>Content number 3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="hrdiv">
          LAST HRDIV
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".hrdiv");
 let last = elements[elements.length - 1];
 last.setAttribute('newattribute', 'example');
 last.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about this is to keep looking for the last *div* tag with *hrdiv* class as long as there are still *hrdiv*

Here is a example of how to do that:

```
var lastHrDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.hrdiv:last-child')[0];
while(lastHrDiv.querySelectorAll('.hrdiv:last-child').length > 0)
lastHrDiv =  lastHrDiv.querySelectorAll('.hrdiv:last-child')[0];
```

And here is a fully working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ep3cm739/2/

Answer (score -1):

As you have a class `hrdiv` for the divs. First select all elements of this classname.

```
 document.querySelector('hrdiv');
```

This will return all elements with this class name. Get the last element and set the attribute of hidden.

```
 document.querySelector('hrdiv').lastElementChild.setAttribute("hidden");
```